# Is there a way to prove that two algebraic equalities are equivalent without directly simplifying?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have this relation:

$$ \frac{3}{x_1 + x_2 + x_3} = \frac{1}{x_1} -  \frac{1}{x_2} + \frac{1}{x_3}$$

And I have this determinant:

$$ \begin{vmatrix}  t_2 - t_1 & \frac{t_2^2 - t_1^2}{2} + t_1 t_2 \\ 
t_3 - t_1  & \frac{t_3^2 - t_1^2}{2} + t_3 t_1 + t_3 t_2\end{vmatrix} =0$$

Is it possible to test if the first formula implies the second or not without bashing the algebra out? Btw, $ t_1 , t_2 ,t_3>0 , t_1 \neq t_2 \neq t_3 $ and $t_1,t_2 , t_3 \neq 0$

I considered taking random points of $t_1,t_2,t_3$ and evaluating the relation at those points but then I thought it may just be luck that the identity is true for only those evaluated points.

For some more context, suppose I am given an expression

$$ 0 = ax^2  + bx +c  \tag{1}$$

And asked if it simplfies into something like:

$$ 0 = a(x-1)^2 + b(x-1) + c$$

I'd just call $ f(x) = ax^2 + bx +c $ and write it's taylor series about the point -1 , now this new taylor polynomial and and og one should be equal once we simplfy everything so taylor polynomial about $x=1$ is also equal to zero.

Comment: What is the relation between $x_i$ and $t_i$?

Comment: @8k14 Not much, it was just an example to show what kind of thing I am asking for